# Возможнаа-ли SQL Injection в данной строке?

Tags: sql, взлом, sql-injection

Как можно сделать SQL Injection при такой строке, возможно-ли это вообще?

```py
cur.execute('SELECT password FROM admins WHERE username=\'%s\'' % request.form['username'].replace('%', '%%'))
```

PS: это ctf, все легально

Comment: `' or 'a' = 'a` — классика не проходит разве?

Comment: Подходит, но мне нужно вывести данные таблицы, там есть что-то по типу `' UNION ALL SELECT concat_ws(0x3a, version(), user(), database())--`, но тут оно не работает

Comment: вы в данной СУБД попробуйте этот селект сначала выполнить, потом уже инъекции делать